# Nested Divs hover content not positioning correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a div over another when the user hovers on the initial div:

Code here (should be same as below):
http://jsfiddle.net/si69j2/rwfbzszn/

My issue is the div that is supposed to appear on hover is not appearing where I thought it would. I've set the position: absolute it is not positioning relative to the promo-card div I expected it to appear over this area, instead it looks like its, or at least it appears to be, over the promo-bar.

I suspect that someone will say this has been answered before, but I don't see it so would appreciate the assistance either way.

```css
.promo-bar {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.promo-card {
    z-index 1;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin:  1.66%;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}

.promo-cardhover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
    position:absolute;
}

.promo-card:hover + .promo-cardhover {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 40%;
    height: inherit;
    background-color: pink;
 }
```

```html
<div class="promo-bar">
    <div class="promo-card promo-local">
        <div class="promo-title">
            Local
        </div>
        <div class="promo-content">
            <span class="promo-price-amount">£120</span>
            <span class="promo-time-period">ipsum</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac faucibus quam. Donec eleifend ex est.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-cardhover">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac faucibus quam. Donec eleifend ex est.
    </div>
    <div class="promo-card promo-national">
        <div class="promo-title">
            Ipsum
        </div>
        <div class="promo-content">
            <span class="promo-price-amount">£1200</span>
            <span class="promo-time-period">ipsum</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac faucibus quam. Donec eleifend ex est.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-cardhover">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac faucibus quam. Donec eleifend ex est.
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

I would also like to have the hovering div to be the same size as the promo-card div.

Comment: why don't you use relative instead of absolute?

Comment: Tried that on the fiddle just did bad things. But thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A. Make the hovering div appear relative to the promo-card**

The reason it is appearing relative to `promo-bar` instead of `promo-card` is because `promo-card` is only a sibling - `promo-bar` is its parent so that's what its position is relative to.

If you move the `promo-cardhover` inside the `promo-card` divs, then it will appear relative to it. (Find the "A1" comments in the code)

Note, You will also need to change the following line in the CSS from

```
.promo-card:hover + .promo-cardhover {
```

to

```
.promo-card:hover .promo-cardhover {
```

The first targets a sibling, but now you need it to target a child instead. (See comment "A2" in the code)

**B. UPDATE: Make the hover div cover the parent `promo-card` div**

**1.** make the promo-card class `position: relative` (you should do this for the above anyway)

```
.promo-card {
    position: relative; /* B1. ADD THIS */
    [... other styles...]
}
```

**2.** Set the absolute position to the corners of the relative parent to cover the full area (This requires the parent to have `position: relative` as in step 1)

```
.promo-cardhover {
    /*  B2. SET ABSOLUTE POSITIONING FOR THE WHOLE DIV */
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;  
    [...]
}
```

**3.** change the width from 40% to 100% - otherwise it will only fill 40% of the area we defined in step 2.

```
.promo-card:hover .promo-cardhover {
    width: 100%; /* B3. CHANGE THIS FROM 40%  */ 
    [...]
}
```

**Working snippet:**

```css
.promo-bar {
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.promo-card {
    z-index 1;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    margin:  1.66%;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
    position: relative; /* B1. ADD THIS */
}

.promo-cardhover {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s linear 0s;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 100;
    position:absolute;
    /*  B2. SET ABSOLUTE POSITIONING FOR THE WHOLE DIV */
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0
}

/* A2. Change this CSS to target a child instead of sibling  */
.promo-card:hover .promo-cardhover {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%; /* B3. CHANGE THIS FROM 40%  */ 
    height: inherit;
    background-color: pink;
 }
```

```html
<div class="promo-bar">
    <div class="promo-card promo-local">
        <div class="promo-title">
            Local
        </div>
        <div class="promo-content">
            <span class="promo-price-amount">£120</span>
            <span class="promo-time-period">ipsum</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac faucibus quam. Donec eleifend ex est.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- A1. MOVE promo-cardhover DIV TO HERE! -->
        <div class="promo-cardhover">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac faucibus quam. Donec eleifend ex est.
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="promo-card promo-national">
        <div class="promo-title">
            Ipsum
        </div>
        <div class="promo-content">
            <span class="promo-price-amount">£1200</span>
            <span class="promo-time-period">ipsum</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac faucibus quam. Donec eleifend ex est.</p>
        </div>

        <!-- A1. MOVE promo-cardhover DIV TO HERE! -->
        <div class="promo-cardhover">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas ac faucibus quam. Donec eleifend ex est.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I had  a good hunch no that but when I tried it the whole thing stopped working. Will check out the code and work out the differences

Comment: @AppHandwerker No problem! I realised I'd forgot to mention the CSS change in my answer.  So there are just 2 changes required: move your `promo-cardhover` divs and change that one line of CSS to target the children instead of siblings.

Comment: any way to set the width and height to match the parent

Comment: @AppHandwerker You can change the width to the same as the parent (its currently set to 40%) because they are both relative to the same thing, but the parents height depends on the content, so the only way to make a=equal height would be to use javascript.

Comment: Thanks as I'd tried making it 100% thinking that would contain it within the promo-card div but I see it doesn't work that way. Thanks again, as technically that's another question ;)

Comment: @AppHandwerker actually, thinking about it, you could actually achieve it without javascript because you are using absolute positioning. Technically it is another question, but I'll update my answer here anyway... just give me a minute!

Comment: Yep I found that also myself, thanks for updating this answer though. As the JS version was a hassle to get to update on resizing.